# Who owns the air above a balcony (to build a Succah)?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, sukkah, real-estate

Contemporary buildings in Jerusalem for Haredim are built in such a manner, that the balcony of the first floor extends to, say, 20 feet, 2nd floor 17 feet, 3rd floor 14 etc, so each one has 3 feet of the skyline above the balcony to accommodate for a Kosher Succah.

A neighbor on a higher floor wants to hang an air conditioner behind his wall right above the "Sucah space" of the floor beneath.

Can he do it? And who owns the air above that "Sucah space" part of the balcony?

Comment: It’s not quite the same case, but perhaps the final Mishnah in Bava Metzia is relevant.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=qqwySPIbk5U

Answer (score 2):

In the specific case which the poster describes the building is built in such a way to allow each neighbor to have a Succah area. Thus the upper neighbor does not have a right to block his lower neighbor from utilizing his Succah rights, as this is part of the way the buildings rights are distributed and all the tenants who live in the building must comply.

This is the Psak both of Rav YS Eliyashiv ZTL and of R' Nissim  Karelitz.

Comment: +1 But what's the Psak - if it is signed in the agreement it would hold anyway,  if not - what's the Psak against an agreement?

Comment: @AlBerko No signed agreement is needed. Since this is the way the building was originally built it obligates anyone who lives there to comply.

Comment: If those are monetary rights, and they are, they are subject to an agreement. I can buy the rights to put air conditioners everywhere, for example, from all my neighbours

Comment: BTW, what would the sources be? Any Choshen Mishpat relevant?

Comment: @AlBerko If the upper neighbor bought those rights from the neighbor below, there would be no question here. Obviously, the question was when he did not.

Comment: +1 but a proper reference to the psakim mentioned would be great

Comment: @ribbis Shouldn't it depend on building regulations and the contract when your buying it?